# Dockerfile RUN - file not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to execute (RUN) a script but I'm getting a not file found error:

The line is: `RUN settings/certs/install-certs.sh`

The other lines that use files from the same path don't cause any issues.

What Am I missing here?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM container-registry.foo.net/maven:3.6.1-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x settings/certs/install-certs.sh
RUN settings/certs/install-certs.sh
RUN mvn clean install -s settings/maven/docker-settings.xml
```

Output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon    218MB
Step 1/13 : FROM container-registry.foo.net/maven:3.6.1-alpine as build
 ---> 7445f83cd169
Step 2/13 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b08dcd4a3395
Step 3/13 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c843717f9c58
Step 4/13 : RUN chmod +x settings/certs/install-certs.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 17c6546c749b
Step 5/13 : RUN settings/certs/install-certs.sh
 ---> Running in 106d58b6bb25
/bin/sh: settings/certs/install-certs.sh: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c settings/certs/install-certs.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Comment: Is the `settings/certs` folder created by you and copied with `COPY . .` or is this a folder coming from `container-registry.foo.net/maven`?

Comment: What is the very first line of the file?  Are you working on a Windows host; are you sure the file has Unix line endings?

Comment: David, yes that was the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turn out the line separator was the reason of the failure, replacing `CRLF` to `LF` did the trick.

Hard to identify when the error says "file not found".